# como popular o array de objetos com dados do SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Bom vamos lá, eu estou fazendo um aplicação, essa terá vários nomes de aluno.
Fiz um método que adicionar cada nome em uma tabela do BD. no bd fica assim(Antonio, Pedro, Caio, Felipe......).

Preciso que esse dados do BD seja recuperado e fique no ARRAY da classe Aluno.

```
     //Vetor da Classe aluno
    Aluno[] alunos = bancoDeDados.obterAlunos();
```

OBS** Esse método não tem nada escrito, pois eu não sei como fazer, se precisará ter return ou void.

CLASSE ALUNO:

//Classe Aluno com dados de cada aluno da AETUB como nome, id e presença;
public class Aluno {

```
private String nome;
private int id;
private int presencaTotal;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getPresencaTotal() {
    return presencaTotal;
}

public void setPresencaTotal(int presencaTotal) {
    this.presencaTotal = presencaTotal;
}
```

}

PARA VER O CÓDIGO COMPLETO
[LINK DROPBOX]: < https://www.dropbox.com/s/xv1tl9k7sqkqfbp/MainActivity.java?dl=0 > [LINK DROPBOX]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa fazer uma pesquisa para obter os alunos e obter as informações do `Cursor` da pesquisa. O `SQLiteDatabase` possui as funções `query` ou `rawQuery` que faz as pesquisas com as informações da tabela, colunas etc. Olhe na documentação do `SQLiteDatabase` para mais informações.

```
public Aluno[] obterAlunos() {
    Cursor resultados = bancoDeDados.query("alunos",
                                    new String[]{"id", "nome", "presenca"},
                                    null, null, null, null, null);

    Aluno[] alunos = new Aluno[resultados.getCount()];

    resultados.moveToFirst();

    // Para obter uma string, int, etc de uma coluna, é preciso do índice
    // Aqui os índices são salvos para não precisar procurar por eles
    // no Cursor. Só para otimizar mesmo.
    final int idPos = resultados.getColumnIndex("id");
    final int nomePos = resultados.getColumnIndex("nome");
    final int presencaPos = resultados.getColumnIndex("presenca");

    int pos = 0; // posição atual na array de alunos

    while (!resultados.isAfterLast()) {            
        alunos[pos] = new Aluno();

        alunos[pos].setNome(resultados.getString(nomePos));
        alunos[pos].setId(resultados.getInt(idPos));
        alunos[pos].setPresencaTotal(resultados.getString(presencaPos));

        resultados.moveToNext();
        pos++;
    }

    resultados.close();

    return alunos;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez, vou para de perguntar você está me perseguindo hahahaha. obrigado cara, desculpa o incomodo.